# Where to put custom settings in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have some custom application specific settings, I want to put in a configuration file. Where would I put these? I considered /config/autoload/global.php and/or local.php. But I'm not sure which key(s) I should use in the config array to be sure not to override any system settings.

I was thinking of something like this (e.g. in global.php):

```
return array(
    'settings' => array(
        'settingA' => 'foo',
        'settingB' => 'bar',
    ),
);
```

Is that an agreeable way? If so, how can I access the settings e.g. from within a controller?

Tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In case you need to create custom config file for specific module, you can create additional config file in **module/CustomModule/config** folder, something like this:

```
module.config.php
module.customconfig.php
```

This is content of your **module.customconfig.php** file:

```php
return array(
    'settings' => array(
        'settingA' => 'foo',
        'settingB' => 'bar',
    ),
);
```

Then you need to change **getConfig()** method in **CustomModule/module.php** file:

```php
public function getConfig() {
    $config = array();
    $configFiles = array(
        include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php',
        include __DIR__ . '/config/module.customconfig.php',
    );
    foreach ($configFiles as $file) {
        $config = \Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils::merge($config, $file);
    }
    return $config;
}
```

Then you can use custom settings in controller:

```php
 $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
 $settings = $config["settings"];
```

it is work for me and hope it help you.

Comment: I think this is a better answer as Sam's answer. Although both files are merged and eventually result in the same, this splits the core config from the user config. From which I think it will lead to less faults.

Comment: Just to add to this: it is correct, that a config file that the user may edit should be provided. However it is "wrong" (read: not the nicest way) to do so in the fashion that is outlined here. The community-default is to have one "module.config.php" with very sane defaults for all settings and then to provide a "$modulename.config.php.dist" inside the config folder. This dist file then contains all user-settings as duplicate with lots of explanation of what they do. This file is then to be copied manually to the /config/autoload directory of the application.

Answer (score 12):

You use your `module.config.php`

```
return array(
    'foo' => array(
        'bar' => 'baz'
    )

  //all default ZF Stuff
);
```

Inside your `*Controller.php` you'd call your settings via

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
$config['foo'];
```

It's as simple as that :)

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks for your answer. The settings I'm talking about may be used by more than one module. module.config.php isn't the right place for those, isn’t it? And secondly: How do I know that the array key 'foo' isn't a default key of ZF? Is there an entire list of reserved config keys used by ZF2?

Comment: There is no such list (yet) :S Obviously configuration provided for many different modules may be stored in a separate config like DrBeza pointed out. Accessing such config is done the same way.

Comment: Great, that’s how I’ll do it. Thanks to both you and DrBeza!

Answer (score 9):

You can use any option from the following.

## Option 1

Create one file called config/autoload/custom.global.php. In custom.global.php

```
return array(
    'settings' => array(
        'settingA' => 'foo',
        'settingB' => 'bar'
    )
)
```

And in controller,

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
echo $config['settings']['settingA'];
```

## Option 2

In config\autoload\global.php or config\autoload\local.php

```
return array(
    // Predefined settings if any
    'customsetting' => array(
        'settings' => array(
            'settingA' => 'foo',
            'settingB' => 'bar'
         )
    )
)
```

And in controller,

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
echo $config['customsetting']['settings']['settingA'];
```

## Option 3

In module.config.php

```
return array(
    'settings' => array(
        'settingA' => 'foo',
        'settingB' => 'bar'
    )
)
```

And in controller,

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
echo $config['settings']['settingA'];
```

Answer (score 4):

If you look in `config/application.config.php` it says:

```
'config_glob_paths'    => array(
    'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
),
```

So ZF2 by default will autoload configuration files from `config/autoload/` - so for example you could have `myapplication.global.php` it would get picked up and added into the configuration.

Evan.pro wrote a blog post that touches on this: https://web.archive.org/web/20140531023328/http://blog.evan.pro/environment-specific-configuration-in-zend-framework-2