# disable layout for particular pages in ZF2

Tags: layout, zend-framework2

How to disable particular layout(example:menus.phtml) for particular pages in controller in ZF2?? In the below example menus.phtml should be disable for specific pages. Remaining pages must contain menus.phtml like header and footer.

```
<div>
    header.phtml
</div>
<div>
    menus.phtml
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $this->content; ?>
</div>
<div>
    footer.phtml
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various aproaches to this. Also modules.zendframework has quite a few modules **[here](http://modules.zendframework.com/?query=layout)** that may help you out.

If you are still keen on writing that yourself you could add variables to your layout within your controllers like so:

```
<?php 
//YourController.php
public function someAction()
{
   ...
   $this->layout()->footer = 'default';
   ...
}

//layout.phtml
<?php if ($this->footer === 'default') : ?>
   //show the footer
<?php endif; ?>
```

Doing this is pretty inefficient though. Just imagine you'd need to do this to every action in all the controllers... I sure would not like to do that.

Now zf2 has a service and event layer that could help us out quite a bit here. **[This](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/05/12/understanding-the-zend-framework-2-event-manager/)** is a pretty nice read and introduction to it. You'd just write a service and trigger a event on your controllers/routes/whatever. Now you would also probably like to configure what is shown and what is hidden right? Thats pretty easy, too. Just write yourself a config file and merge it with the global.config like so:

```
<?php
//CustomModule/module.php
public function getConfig() {
   $config = array();
   $configFiles = array(
      include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php',
      include __DIR__ . '/config/module.customconfig.php',
   );
   foreach ($configFiles as $file) {
      $config = \Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils::merge($config, $file);
   }
   return $config;
}
```

**Source: [Where to put custom settings in Zend Framework 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993136/where-to-put-custom-settings-in-zend-framework-2)**

Comment: Looks as if the OP wants just the `menu.phtml` to be hidden rather than the whole layout.

Comment: just the menu.phtml to be hidden.

Comment: Ohhh. Are you using partials within your layout.phtml?

Answer (score -1):

First, get the controller or action name:

```
$controllerName =$this->params('controller');
$actionName = $this->params('action');
```

then in your layout/view script add a simple logic.

```
<?php if ($actionName != 'action that you want to disable the layout/menu'): ?>
    echo $this->render('menus.phtml');
<?php endif; ?>
```